# Can I use my phone's charger to connect arduino M0 pro R3 with computer?

Tags: arduino-pro-mini

I found out that the arduino M0 pro R3 needs either micro HDMI or micro USB.

Since I don't have any micro USB or HDMI adapters, can I use the Samsung galaxy USB/micro adapter to connect?

Comment: If the Samsung cable has a micro-usb on one end, and a usb-a on the other side, then I don't see why not.

Comment: @Gerben I actually tried it, and I did get a successful upload. But the power is 5 volts, and 1.5 amps. Will that be enough? And just to add, can I use a 3 amp, 12 volt Ac/DC adaptor? Or will it fry my arduino?

Comment: You just want to power it, not connect it to a PC? A regular USB port only supplies upto 500mA, so 1.5A is plenty.

Comment: @Gerben And will my arduino be fried if I use a 12 volt, 3 amp AC/DC adaptor as an external power supply?

Comment: What board are you using? The R3 doesn't make sense for the M0, and in the tag you refer to a pro-mini.

Comment: @Gerben My arduino has text saying the board is an M0 R3. It is the arduino.org brand. Should I tag this question as arduino-zero?

Comment: `The allowed input voltage range for this pin is 6-20 V.` [source](http://www.arduino.org/products/boards/4-arduino-boards/arduino-m0-pro). So your 12v adapter is also fine.

Comment: @Gerben You can put all the details discussed in an answer for me to accept. And finally to add: Do the amps matter? What is the maximum amount that can be handled as an external source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echoing what Gerben said, in order to wrap up this question:

- If the Samsung cable has a micro-usb on one end, and a usb-a on the other side, then I don't see why not.
- You just want to power it, not connect it to a PC? A regular USB port only supplies upto 500mA, so 1.5A is plenty.
- The allowed input voltage range for this pin is 6-20 V. source‌​. So your 12v adapter is also fine.

Comment: I actually tried a month ago. Worked. Thanks ;)

Comment: Excellent. This question now has an acknowledged good answer. That's what we like!

Comment: It should be noted that "this pin" (6-20V) is the VIN pin. And not the USB port. To avoid mixing those up. Also, you won't fry a board because your supply can supply more current, the Arduino will simply use the current it needs. If your Arduino pulls more current (by attaching a motor directly) than it can handle, you might indeed harm it, or the power supply.
And, yes, acknowledging the answers pumps up the stats a little ;)